# Customizing the default EE email layout

Tags: templates, email-contact-form

I am using EE's contact form {exp:email:contact_form} for user submitted queries on my site and would like to know if its possible to customize the layout of the email it sends?

Currently I have several fields that need to be sent (first name, last name, mobile, email & message) and I have added them to the message content by naming all the inputs with the

name="message[]"

attribute which adds each field on its own line. Am I able to add in for e.g a header piece of copy ("The following is a query from your website") or labels for the fields ("Firstname: {first_name_input}" ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure can, the secret is in using hidden fields:

To add a generic message you could do:

```
<input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="The following is a query from your website">
```

Or to add a heading for a field do:

```
<label for="cheese">What's the best cheese?</label>
<input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="--favourite cheese--">
<input type="text" id="cheese" name="message[]" value="">
```

That will output something like:

*The following is a query from your website*

*--favourite cheese--*

*Gorgonzola*